# gulp tasks execution in bamboo

Tags: gulp, bamboo

I have added npm task to install all my dependencies in bamboo. This command is working successfully.  Now I want add gulp task. I have  added nodeJS addon in my bamboo plan. Using this I want to execute the gulp command (e.x : gulp minify). I am not able to find the way how to execute this command. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bamboo Node.js Support](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-nodejs-plugin) add-on you referenced features a dedicated [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task. I think it is shipped alongside newer versions of [Atlassian Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) at least, maybe you need a newer version?

The [Node.js Bamboo Plugin (Bitbucket)](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bamboo-nodejs-plugin/overview) page explains how to *Configure dependencies and install modules* for it to work:

> Add the following dependencies (or devDependencies) to the
>   `package.json` file in your Node.js project. These are required if you
>   want to use the "Grunt 0.4.x", "Gulp", "Bower", "Nodeunit" or "Mocha
>   Test Runner" tasks.
>
> - ...
> - Gulp
>
>   - [gulp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp) (v3.3.2 or newer recommended)
> - ...