# Setting up Protractor e2e tests with Bamboo CI

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, protractor, bamboo, angularjs-e2e

We use `Protractor` to automate our *angular app* and now need to run those protractor tests from a `Bamboo CI server`.

I'm new to Bamboo and was wondering if anybody could either show me how to or point me to a web article that would show me how to **trigger/execute my protractor tests from Bamboo server**.

Locally, we run the tests using `gulp protractor` which all run and pass; Now I'd like to execute those same tests from a *Bamboo server*.
I was only able to find some articles on Google that shows how to set up `Selenium with Bamboo`. I understand that `Protractor uses Selenium` under the hood but am just not sure if Protractor would follow the same steps as Selenium does, when setting it up on a Bamboo CI machine.

*If Protractor follows a different setup than Selenium on a Bamboo CI machine*, could someone please **point me to either another article or simply show the steps** here if it's simple to do.

Comment: What have you tried? You're always going to get more help if you post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

This question is already a few months old, but it's still unanswered, so I try to help. ;)

I haven't tried it by myself, but there is a gulp task in bamboo. (as also mentioned here: [gulp tasks execution in bamboo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701362/gulp-tasks-execution-in-bamboo))
[image: task type selection: gulp]

I think you have to install node.js on you bamboo server and then you can just add the gulp task to your plan and configure it for your needs.
[image: gulp configuration form]

Short field description:

- *Node.js executable*: should be filled if you have installed Node.js on your bamboo server, or select the correct one if you have installed multiple versions of Node.js (I haven't installed Node.js, so there is no executable available for me)
- *Gulp executable*: I'm not so femiliar with gulp, but I think this default value should be correct in the most cases.
- *Task*: In your case you should insert `protractor` here